# Вытащить все записи из 3 таблицы

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
          WHEN tag THEN (SELECT title FROM tag WHERE id IN(tag))        
    END
    FROM news WHERE id = 3992
```

Таким образом на выходе мне удается вытащить всего 1 тег и на выходе он как строчка. Возможно получить список тегов из третей таблицы в виде массива? Из-под подзапроса?

**news**

```
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   ID  |   name         |   tag_ID  
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   1   |   SIMPLE1      |   1,2
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   2   |   SIMPLE2      |   3
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   3   |   SIMPLE3      |   
+-------+----------------+-----------
```

**tag**

```
+-------+----------------+
|   ID  |   name         |
+-------+----------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE5      |
+-------+----------------+
|   2   |   SIMPLE6      |
+-------+----------------+
|   3   |   SIMPLE7      |
+-------+----------------+
```

К примеру, берем `1` запись из новостей, у нее теги `1,2`

То есть, как в запросе выполнить запрос во вторую таблицу и вытащить из нее теги с id `1,2`

Comment: Можете показать данные из этих таблиц и какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Вы говорите про третью таблицу, но даже в примере запроса только 2 таблицы...

Comment: left join, group by и агрегатные функции.

Comment: 2 таблицы, верно.  1 таблица - поле tag содержит id записей из второй к примеру `1,2,3,4`(строчка). left join на сколько я помню не подойдет, поскольку необходимо указывать пересечения. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Добавил пример таблиц в вопрос

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3. А показанные Вами примеры - ниачём.

Comment: Отредактировалл